# The STRTOSET function expects a tuple set expression for the 1 argument. A string or numeric expression was used

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I'm using reporting services, using parameters, so I have query like this:

```
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY { [Measures].[ReclamosBSC_Reclamos] } ON COLUMNS, 
    NON EMPTY { ([Dim_Tiempo_].[Anio].[Anio].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_Tiempo_].[Mes].[Mes].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_Tiempo_].[NombreMesAbreviado].[NombreMesAbreviado].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[IdGrupo].[IdGrupo].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[NombreGrupo].[NombreGrupo].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[IdDivision].[IdDivision].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[NombreDivision].[NombreDivision].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[IdPlanta].[IdPlanta].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[Planta].[Planta].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_ClientePadre_].[Dim_ClientePadre_].[Dim_ClientePadre_].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
     DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_VALUE, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT 
        ( STRTOSET(@DimTiempoMes) ) ON COLUMNS 
    FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT 
            ( STRTOSET(@DimTiempoAnio) ) ON COLUMNS 
        FROM 
            [BSC]
    )
) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

It runs correctly when I use query designer, but when I try to see Preview of my report it returns:

> The STRTOSET function expects a tuple set expression for the 1
>   argument. A string or numeric expression was used.

Can someone explain me what is wrong with my query?

Comment: What `@DimTiempoMes` and `@DimTiempoAnio` parameter values are being used when you Preview the report? Are they the same as when you run it in the query designer?

Comment: yes I want to use it into my Preview @jhenninger

Comment: I use it to send parameters to query then filter by them. @jhenninger

Comment: Can you share the values that you are sending for the two parameters when you Preview the report?

Comment: @jhenninger  yes one is year and equals to 2017 and the other is month and it equals to 9, so I sending  `DimTiempoAnio` = 2017 and  `DimTiempoMes` = 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the Preview functionality is setting your year and month parameter values to "2017" and "9", respectively, you can rewrite your query as follows:

```
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY { [Measures].[ReclamosBSC_Reclamos] } ON COLUMNS, 
    NON EMPTY { ([Dim_Tiempo_].[Anio].[Anio].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_Tiempo_].[Mes].[Mes].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_Tiempo_].[NombreMesAbreviado].[NombreMesAbreviado].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[IdGrupo].[IdGrupo].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[NombreGrupo].[NombreGrupo].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[IdDivision].[IdDivision].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[NombreDivision].[NombreDivision].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[IdPlanta].[IdPlanta].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_PlantaCentro_].[Planta].[Planta].ALLMEMBERS 
     * [Dim_ClientePadre_].[Dim_ClientePadre_].[Dim_ClientePadre_].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
     DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_VALUE, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT 
        { ( STRTOMEMBER('[Dim_Tiempo_].[Mes].[Mes].[' + @DimTiempoMes + ']') ) } ON COLUMNS 
    FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT 
            { ( STRTOMEMBER('[Dim_Tiempo_].[Anio].[Anio].[' + @DimTiempoAnio + ']') ) } ON COLUMNS 
        FROM 
            [BSC]
    )
) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Using nested subqueries will allow you to include the year and month on your ROWS axis in the SELECT clause. If you used a WHERE clause, you would get an error when including the year and month in the SELECT clause.

Comment: Problem is I set param with value I want, I can pass 2017 or 2016 or 2015, so query search depending of value I pass, that´s why I have parameter. I need WHERE clause? how can I add WHERE clause to my code?

Comment: I updated the answer with updates to your original query. This is all assuming that the parameter values are being sent in as you mentioned.

Comment: But DimTiempoAnio  and DimTiempoMes are not precharged in report, when I run preview, I have 2 columns with this fields, there I insert value of parameters, then I clic "View Report", and now report charge values with parameters I sending. Thats why I need WHERE clause or I´m wrong?

Comment: The query in my answer contains the original parameters which are set dynamically when you Preview. Is this updated query giving you the same error as your original query?

Comment: No it throws another issue now, thank you for your answer it helpfull alot!

Comment: I found some trouble with query you provide.. Now query dont return any fields from select. Why it occurs?

Comment: It's hard to diagnose your issue without knowing how the Preview functionality is setting the parameter values. Are you able to run the SQL Server Profiler to see what query is actually being executed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157838/discussion-between-jhenninger-and-pepe).